# Build Size is Different

Tags: ios, swift3, app-store

I have Create Build with development Certificate the App Size is 10 MB, But i have create build for distribution certificate for uploading to App Store the App Size is 99 MB.

Answer (score 1):

It's not surprising that the distribution version is larger than the development version. When you build an app for a specific device during development, Xcode only needs to compile a binary for one processor, and it only needs to include the resources that would be used on that device. When you build for distribution, Xcode builds a fat binary that includes slices for every processor. The uploaded package also has to include versions of each image resource at all the resolutions that might be used on any device. The result is an application archive that includes a lot more than what's needed for any single device.

The fact that the package you upload to the App Store is large doesn't mean that the app that your users eventually download will be as large, though. The App Store will use [*app thinning*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) to deliver only those components that are needed to each device.